# Reconnecting to database results in null terminated binary strings

Tags: python, bcrypt, pymysql

I'm working on a password verification system. I have a binary(60) column to store the password, which I'm hashing using `bcrypt`. When I use the same `pymysql` connection to store and retrieve the password, I am able to verify the password. However, when I create a new connection, the password no longer verifies.

In particular the issue I'm encountering is that the result returned when I have a new connection has a bunch of null bytes at the end. I tried stripping these, but the result still doesn't match. (`b'$2b$12$Y9iqA5faupXeUcCzS8jrEOkBdQrpLOCUp\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'` vs `b'$2b$12$Yzpcua55O0RSNqqSzTZ/k.JcZy6ValV8uTXLpcEzXHM8MYLVlFSoa'`)

Is there something wrong with the way I'm storing or encoding these hashes?

```
# CONNECTING #
conn = pymysql.connect(os.environ["db_host"], 
                        user=os.environ["db_user"], 
                        passwd=os.environ["db_password"],
                        db=os.environ["db_name"], 
                        connect_timeout=5, 
                        charset='utf8mb4')
# STORING #
newlyhashed = bcrypt.hashpw(apikey.encode(), bcrypt.gensalt())
cur.execute("UPDATE api_users \
                          SET secret = _binary %s \
                          WHERE api_users.name = %s", 
            [pymysql.Binary(newlyhashed),"user"])
# RETRIEVING #
dcur.execute("SELECT secret FROM api_users \
              WHERE api_users.name = %s","user")
# VERIFYING #
verify = row["secret"]
bcrypt.checkpw(apikey.encode(), verify)
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference between disconnecting and reconnecting should have told me! If the returned result is different from two different connections, you may have omitted the commit.

I believe that the NULL bytes are an artifact of when I tried to update the hash using PhpMyAdmin. Stripping them didn't make a difference because the hash was actually of a different password.